# Using parent references in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, reference

I was wondering whether using a reference of some interface instead of pointer could result in some complications that I am overlooking. The reason why I want to do this is to make clear which objects should 'delete' pointers given to them on construction and which ones should just use it and not worry about other objects lifetimes to allow for multiple instances to share one object. (shared_ptr is not an option)

Here is an example:

```
class Parent
{
public:
    virtual void WhoAmI() { printf("Parent\n"); }
};
class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    void WhoAmI() { printf("Child\n"); }
};

class ParentUser
{
public:
    ParentUser(Parent& parent)  : _parent(parent)   {}
public:
    Parent& _parent;
};

class ParentOwner
{
public:
    ParentOwner(Parent* pParent): _pParent(pParent), _parentUser(*pParent) {}
    ~ParentOwner() { delete _pParent; }
public:
    Parent*     _pParent;
    ParentUser _parentUser; 
};


int main ()
{   
    Parent* pParent = new Child();
    ParentOwner parentOwner(pParent);
    parentOwner._parentUser._parent.WhoAmI();

    char stopper;
    cin >> stopper;
    return 0;
}
```

This worked correctly and the output was the expected: 'Child'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of a reference to indicate use of an object and a pointer to indicate ownership is perfectly fine. You’ve simply defined your own convention for ownership, and everything should work **as long as all your code follows that convention**. Note that you can only have one object in your system that has a pointer to the object to be deleted.

In your example, the Child object can be passed as a constructor argument to only one ParentOwner object.

Answer (score 0):

In general the object that allocated the memory should be reponsible for freeing it.
Deleting it in other objects can lead to trouble.

Imagine this scenario:

1. Object A creates "Obj".
2. Object A passes it on to object B
3. Object B deletes it.
4. Object A who doesn't know "Obj" was deleted passes it now to object C.
5. Object C tries to use "Obj". BOOM!